# Non latin characters replace on .keyup() does not work when typing fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input

I have jQuery code that replace Cyrillic user input with Latin chars. This work fine when user input is not too fast (60-70 chars per minute) but when user typing faster then this, it mixed Cyrillic chars and Latin chars, probably because cannot catch `keyup` event in time. How can I fix this?

```
$("input[name*=Name]").not("input[name*=Main]").keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46 || e.keyCode === 9 || e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 17 || e.keyCode === 18 || e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 40 || e.keyCode === 16 || e.keyCode === 20) {
                return false;
            } else {
                var englishchars = ["a", "b", "v", "g", "d", "e", "yo", "zh", "z", "i", "yi", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "r", "s", "t", "u", "f", "kh", "c", "ch", "sh", "shch", "i", "e", "yu", "ya", ""];
                var slavicchars = ["а", "б", "в", "г", "д", "е", "ё", "ж", "з", "и", "й", "к", "л", "м", "н", "о", "п", "р", "с", "т", "у", "ф", "х", "ц", "ч", "ш", "щ", "ы", "э", "ю", "я", "ь"];
                var verified = String.fromCharCode(e.wich).match(/[^а-яё]/);
                if (verified) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var lastchar = this.value.length > 1 ? this.value.substr(-1) : this.value;
                    var russiancharindex = jQuery.inArray(lastchar, slavicchars);
                    if (russiancharindex > 0) {
                        var englishcharindex = englishchars[russiancharindex];
                        this.value = this.value.replace(lastchar, englishcharindex);
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (...) probably because cannot catch keyup event in time (...)

It's because `keyup` event is catched when the key is released, while the character is inserted into textbox when key is pressed.
So, having two keys pressed for a short while (typing fast), both characters already exists in the textbox, then releasing keys one by one, you're checking only the last character of the input `value`, but first released key was addressed to one before last char.

```
var lastchar = this.value.length > 1 ? this.value.substr(-1) : this.value;
var russiancharindex = jQuery.inArray(lastchar, slavicchars);
// ...
```

Also for that reason, it will not work when you move back the cursor to insert a letter in the middle of the text.

---

How about this?

On each `keyup` it will match every single *non-ascii* character in the string (instead of matching the last character only).
Note. Updating input value will cause the cursor to lose its current position and will be moved at the end of the input. To prevent that (if you edit the field somewhere in the middle), store its position before update and restore after that.

(shortened your `if(e.keyCode ...)` condition and added a space [32] to keyCodes)

```
// keep these variables outside of the handler, so that they're not redeclared unnecessarily:
var charsObject = {
    'a' : 'а',
    'б' : 'b',
    'в' : 'v',
    // ...
}, keyCodes = [8,46,9,13,17,18,32,37,38,39,40,16,20];

$("input[name*=Name]:not([name*=Main])").keyup(function(e){
    if (keyCodes.indexOf( e.keyCode ) < 0) {
        // store current cursor position:
        var start = this.selectionStart, end = this.selectionEnd;
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\u0000-\u007f]/g, function(char, key) {
            // return replacement letter, or the original letter if it's not a "charsObject" key:
            return charsObject[char] || char;
        }));
        // restore cursor position after field update:
        this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/57murLze/)

Comment: Look interesting. Let me try.

Comment: I can't get why your code work in JSFiddle and not on my browser.

Comment: You code work for latin chars (as in your JSFiddle), but when one part of array is Cyrillic chars, it's not working. No, there is no errors in console.

Comment: @andrey.shedko , updated code in the answer (and fiddle)

Comment: @andrey.shedko , updated once again. It will match only the non-latin characters, not the whole text :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got even better solution.

```
$("input[name*=Name]:not([name*=Main])").focusout(function (e) {
            var englishchars = ["a", "b", "v", "g", "d", "e", "yo", "zh", "z", "i", "yi", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "r", "s", "t", "u", "f", "kh", "c", "ch", "sh", "shch", "i", "e", "yu", "ya", "'"];
            var slavicchars = ["а", "б", "в", "г", "д", "е", "ё", "ж", "з", "и", "й", "к", "л", "м", "н", "о", "п", "р", "с", "т", "у", "ф", "х", "ц", "ч", "ш", "щ", "ы", "э", "ю", "я", "ь"];
            var t = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            var word = new Array();
            $.each(t.split(""), function (key, val) {
                var verified = String.fromCharCode(e.wich).match(/[^а-яё]/);
                if (verified) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var russiancharindex = jQuery.inArray(val, slavicchars);
                    if (russiancharindex >= 0) {
                        var englishcharindex = englishchars[russiancharindex];
                        word.push(englishcharindex);
                    } else {
                        word.push(val);
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
                return word;
            });
            $(this).val(word.join("").replace(",", ""));
        });
```